# How do I inject a value into Zend Form?

Tags: zend-form

I have a select element in a Zend Form.  To populate the multiOptions array of the element, I call a static method on a model which returns an array.  I need to pass a parameter to the static method, but first I need to get the parameter into Zend Form.  How can I do this?

I tried passing an array to the Zend Form constructor, then using getAttrib() from within the form.  This worked OK however the parameter also shows as a HTML parameter on the form, which is not my intention.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent constructor options from appearing as form attributes, you have to specify `setter` for each passed option.

Example:

```
class Forms_Hello extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_names = array();

    public function init()
    {
        $names = $this->getNames();
    }

    public function setNames($names)
    {
        $this->_names = $names
    }

    public function getNames()
    {
        return $this->_names;
    }
}

$form = new Forms_Hello(array(
    'names' => array(
        1 => 'hello',
        2 => 'world'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have settled for setting this from outside the form object, after the object is instantiated.  Not exactly what I was looking for but workable, nonetheless...

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Form` constructor looks for a specific pattern in method's names in your form. The pattern is `setMethodName`. the constructor calls the `MethodName()` in your class and pass the parameter to it.

So you'll have this in your class :

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{

    protected $_myParameters;

    public function setParams($myParameters)
    {
        $this->_myParameters = $myParameters;
    }
```

And you pass the parameters to your form with :

```
$form = new My_Form( array('params' => $myParameters) );
```

So instead of `params` you can use any other names ( of course if it doesn't already exists in `Zend_Form` ).